# What/Where is the "Symbol Browser" in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, ide

OK, so this is the background... I'm going to manually fix the multiple resource header files in our project. That involves fixing this value, among other things: `#define _APS_NEXT_SYMED_VALUE` ... that is automatically written to in (normally) `resource.h`.

It's documented as having this purpose:

> _APS_NEXT_SYMED_VALUE is the next symbol value that will be issued when
>   you manually assign a symbol value
>   using the New command in the Symbol
>   Browser.

But where is the *Symbol* Browser!? I want to know, as I want to know what I'm setting these values for. I know what the *Class* Browser/View is, I know what the *Object* Browser is, but this is driving me nuts. :-D I've even googled for `"visual studio" "symbol browser"`, but came up with no documentation of the browser in question. I know I'm at the right place if there's a "New" command there, and I can manually assign a symbol value in it. Hmm...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Visual Studio, select the **View**/**Resource View** menu option then, in the **Resource View**, right-click the .rc file and select **Resource Symbols**.

Documentation can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7h5sz68.aspx) on MSDN.