# Symbol table entries in visual studio 2008

Tags: c, visual-studio-2008

The following two links helped me to locate the symbol table in visual studio.

[What/Where is the "Symbol Browser" in Visual Studio 2008?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298638/what-where-is-the-symbol-browser-in-visual-studio-2008)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sxdy04be.aspx

I executed a simple program to see the values in symboltable but nothing is inside the .rc file.

```
int main()
{
 int a=10;
 int *p;
 int k[]={10,20,30};
 return 0;
}
```

I expected that the symbol table will contain a as an integer type.But nothing is there in the .rc file.Please help me understand what to do to see the symbol table entries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a misunderstanding. In this context, *Symbol Browser* refers to the *Resource Symbols* dialog of a resource file. It has nothing to do with the symbols in C code. Furthermore, .rc files are resource files containing icons, menus, dialogs, string etc. A compiled program contains hardly any symbol information as they are not needed at run-time.

**Update:**

VisualStudio stores symbol information in a separate file with the .pdb extension. It's mainly use for the debugger. The .pdb file is in a proprietary and undocumented format but you can access it with the [Debug Interface Access SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x93ctkx8.aspx).

Comment: :Thanks codo.How to look into the compilers symbol table to see how the compiler recorded the declaration of int a. I need to check with the int *p and int a[].How compiler is recording both the declarations.